# Symfony 4 - JsonResponse returns a non-empty object as empty

Tags: api, object, request, symfony4, jsonresponse

I'm trying to return the result of an API request (using Postman) in Symfony.

Here is my relevant controller code:

```
/**
 * @Route("/apis/login", name="api_login")
 */
public function login(Request $request, UserRepository $userRepository): Response
{
    $cin = json_decode($request->getContent(),true)["cin"];
    $password = json_decode($request->getContent(),true)["password"];
    $user = $userRepository->findOneBy(['cin'=>$cin, 'password'=>$password]);
    if($user!=null){
        return new JsonResponse(json_encode($user));
    }else{
        return new JsonResponse("false");
    }
}
```

And this is the request body:

[image]

However, this is what I get as a result:

[image]

In my code, if I change this line `return new JsonResponse(json_encode($user));` to this one `return new JsonResponse(serialize($user));` , I get this:

[image]

Which proves that the returned object is not empty. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: You don't need encode parameter, pass parameter as array. like JsonResponse(['id'=>$user->getId()])

Comment: Good idea! I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed it! I've just converted the user object to an array. So, I've changed my code like so:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/apis/login", name="api_login")
 */
public function login(Request $request, UserRepository $userRepository): Response
{
    $cin = json_decode($request->getContent(),true)["cin"];
    $password = json_decode($request->getContent(),true)["password"];
    $user = $userRepository->findOneBy(['cin'=>$cin, 'password'=>$password]);
    if($user!=null){
        $arr = (array) $user;
        foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
            $newkey = substr($k,17);
            $arr[$newkey] = $arr[$k];
            unset($arr[$k]);
        }
        return new JsonResponse($arr);
    }else{
        return new JsonResponse("false");
    }
}
```